# how to implement splash screen in class extends Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

***earlier i was using below code that was working:***

```
package com.usd.quiztest;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Logo extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.logo_screen);

        Thread background = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // Thread will sleep for 5 seconds
                    sleep(2000);

                    // After 5 seconds redirect to another intent
                    Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),First.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    //Remove activity
                    finish();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };

        // start thread
        background.start();
    }
}
```

**but when i used this code insted of above code (class extends activity / class extends Fragment)**

```
    package com.usd.quiztest;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Logo extends Fragment{ 

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.logo_screen, null);
    }
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Thread background = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // Thread will sleep for 5 seconds
                    sleep(2000);

                    // After 5 seconds redirect to another intent
                    Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),First.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    //Remove activity
                    finish();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };

        // start thread
        background.start();

    }
}
```

**my app end-up with fortunately stop error**

**help me to implement splash screen in class extends Fragment**

Error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Intent cannot be resolved to a type Logo.java   /QuizTest/src/com/usd/quiztest  line 25 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Intent cannot be resolved to a type Logo.java   /QuizTest/src/com/usd/quiztest  line 25 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method finish() is undefined for the type new Thread(){}    Logo.java   /QuizTest/src/com/usd/quiztest  line 29 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type new Thread(){}    Logo.java   /QuizTest/src/com/usd/quiztest  line 25 Java Problem
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.usd.quiztest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <supports-screens>
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
    </supports-screens>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.usd.quiztest.Logo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"            
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />               
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.usd.quiztest.First"            
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" >            
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.usd.quiztest.Q1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>        
         <activity
            android:name="com.usd.quiztest.Q2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.usd.quiztest.Q3"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.usd.quiztest.Q4"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.usd.quiztest.Q5"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.usd.quiztest.FinalPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.usd.quiztest.Score"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: you should not use splash screen its not a good idea http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Comment: Where are you adding your fragment and what is it being added to ?
Post some more code and the error you're getting

Answer (score 1):

You can call your run() method inside SplashScreenActivity.

My project is using appcompat_v7 library.

After the delay 2000 in milliseconds, run() method will be executed.

SplashScreenActivity.java

```
package com.usd.quiztest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements Runnable {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new SplashScreenFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
    }

    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

activity_splash_screen.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.usd.quiztest.SplashScreenActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

SplashScreenFragment.java

```
package com.usd.quiztest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SplashScreenFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash_screen, container, false);
    }
}
```

fragment_splash_screen.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.usd.quiztest.SplashScreenActivity$SplashScreenFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/splash_screen" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Fragment class would have a Fragment Activity class, right? or related Acivity class right? You need to start your Splash Activity there, and once the activity finishes, you can load your new Fragment using Fragment manager, from there on.